# Python requests module - send only specified headers

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I need to send a post request to a web server with only 'Host' & 'Content-Length' headers. I have specified these two headers in the dictionary which I pass to requests module, but it adds 'Accept', 'Accept-Encoding', 
'User-Agent' headers.

Python code:

```
headers = {'Content-Length': content_length, 'Host': 'Server-1:8080'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.request.headers)
```

Actual request headers sent:

```
{'Accept': '*/*', 'Host': 'Server-1:8080', 'Content-Length': '3072', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/3.4.1 Windows/7', 'Connection': 'keep-alive, 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
```

How can I limit the headers sent by requests module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a read of [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) it looks like those are session level parameters which you can force to be omitted by setting their values to `None`.

```
headers = {'Content-Length': content_length, 'Host': 'Server-1:8080',
           'User-Agent': None, 'Connection': None, 'Accept-Encoding': None}
```

Comment: These days, setting `Host`, `User-Agent` or `Accept-Encoding` to `None` doesn't work. It causes Requests to send them [with their default values](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6251) instead of not sending them at all. For those 3 you have to do `import urllib3` then `headers = {'Host': urllib3.util.SKIP_HEADER, 'User-Agent': urllib3.util.SKIP_HEADER, 'Accept-Encoding': urllib3.util.SKIP_HEADER}`. See [#5671](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5671#issuecomment-1006735307) for details.